# State value not updating in react

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on my first React application and I'm not understanding why the State doesn't have the updated value.

Here is my code:

```
const SlideOutPanel = forwardRef((props: any, ref: any) => {

    const initCss: string = 'is-slide-out-panel';

    const [compClass, setCompClass] = useState(initCss);

    useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
        open() {
            open();
        },
        close() {
            close();
        },
    }));
    function refresh(): any {

        let classVal: string = compClass;

        if (props.direction === 'left-to-right') {
            classVal = `${classVal} left-to-right`;
        } else if (props.direction === 'right-to-left') {
            classVal = `${classVal} right-to-left`;
        }

        if (Types().boolVal(props.userOverlay)) {
            classVal = `${classVal} use-overlay`;
        }

        if (Types().boolVal(props.pushMain)) {
            classVal = `${classVal} push-effect`;
        }

        if (props.theme === 'dark') {
            classVal = `${classVal} theme-dark`;
        }

        setCompClass(classVal);

        let classValdd: string = compClass;
    }

    function open(): void {
        let classVal: string = compClass;
    }


    useEffect(() => {
        refresh();
    }, []);

    return (
        <section id={id} className={compClass}>
            <div className="content">{props.children}</div>
        </section>
    );
});
```

I call refresh() when the components first load, which basically sets the className based on the passed props. At the end of the function, I set state "setCompClass" the value of "classVal" which works as I verified in Chrome Debugger.  But on the same function I have the following line "let classValdd: string = compClass;" just to check what the value of "compClass" is and its always "is-slide-out-panel".

At first I thought it has to do with a delay.  So when I call open() to do the same check, the value is still "is-slide-out-panel".  So I'm a bit confused.  Am I not able to read the state value "compClass"?  Or am I misunderstanding its usage?

Comment: state changes in react are asychronous. how are you checking its value? console log?

Comment: console it before `setCompClass(classVal);
`

Comment: you can pass a callback to `setCompClass` ... aka `setCompClass(classVal, () => console.log(compClass))`

Comment: I was just putting the debugger to look in Chrome Debugger.  I wasn't aware it was asynchronous.    Let me check using your recommendation azium

Comment: Mani when I debug it in Chrome Debugger classVal has the right values.  I want aware that it was asynchronous

Answer (score 0):

Setting the state in React acts like an async function.
Meaning that when you set it, it most likely won't finish updating until the next line of code runs.

So doing this will not work -

```js
setCompClass(classVal);

let classValdd: string = compClass;
```

You will likely still end up with the previous value of the state.

I'm not exactly sure what specifically you're trying to do here with the `classValdd` variable at the end of the function block, but with function components in React, if we want to act upon a change in a state piece, we can use the built-in `useEffect` hook.

It should look like this -

```js
useEffect(() => {
   // Stuff we want to do whenever compClass gets updated.
}, [compClass]);
```

As you can see, `useEffect` receives 2 parameters.
The first is a callback function, the second is a dependency array.
The callback function will run whenever there is a change in the value of any of the members in that array.